# Integral with substitution

Tags: integration

Integral : $$\displaystyle \int \sqrt{x^2 - 5x + 4}~ dx$$
Found the solution, can't find step by step, the substitution $x-2=u$ was my first try, after that I am just stuck. :)

I am here: $\displaystyle \int \sqrt{u^2 -1} du$ and it seems so easy :)

Comment: $u = x-2 \implies \sqrt{u^2 -(u - 2)}$ where $x = u-2$. That is $(x-2)^2 = x^2-{\bf 4}x + 4 \neq x^2 - 5x + 4 = (x-2)^2 - x$.

Comment: My point is you cannot use $u = x-2$ to obtain the $\int \sqrt {u^2 - 1} \,du$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: $$\sqrt{x^2-5x+4}=\sqrt{(x-\frac{5}{2})^2-\frac{9}{4}}\\\frac{3}{2}\cosh(t)=x-\frac{5}{2}$$

Comment: cosh(x) = ( e x + e -x )/2 ? Because i never used it before, and I'm not sure what it means. Maybe with another term or so

Comment: Well if you're not aware of the $\cosh$ you could use $sec(t)$ instead and the identity $\sec^2(t)-1=\tan^2$.If you want to use $\cosh(t)$ then you have that $\cosh^2(t)-1=\sinh^2(t)$ and then you can take $\sinh(t)=\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{2}$

Comment: Yeah, i brought it to an end. Not sure if I also did is correct, but I finished it :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have $\int \sqrt{u^2-1}\, \mathrm{d}u$, try setting $u=\cosh(t)$ (or alternatively, $u=\sec(\theta)$).

Comment: Maybe the context will help, because it should be much easier:)

Comment: so i have the function f=x^2 - 5x +4, and i have to prove that

Comment: 0 <= (4)Integral(5) sqrt(fx)dx <= 2

Comment: So to place the integral between two values. 4 and 5 are the borders, 4 is down

Comment: The OP doesn't have $\sqrt{u^2 - 1}$ using his/her substitution.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's a -x, not -1

Answer (score 0):

First complete the square to obtain $\sqrt{(x-5/2)^2-9/4}=\frac12\sqrt{(2x-5)^2-9}.$

Then let $u=2x-5$ and therefore $du=2dx.$  So now your integral is:

$$\int\sqrt{u^2-9}\;du$$

Now envision a right triangle with acute angle $\theta$ whose opposite side is $\sqrt{u^2-9}.$  That makes the adjacent side $3$ and the hypotenuse $u,$ so that you can use $\sec\theta=u/3.$  Now you have $du=3\sec\theta\tan\theta,$ so that your integral becomes:

$$9\int\tan\theta \sec^2\theta\;d\theta.$$

From here, you will have to use the identity $1+\tan^2\theta=\sec^2\theta$ and integration by parts to get the final answer.

Good luck!